# Is it feasible to record a program state in Valgrind/DrMemory and then restore that?

Tags: linux, fork, valgrind, memcheck, dr-memory

I have a program that loads a big chunk of data at startup. That takes up a rather long time and therefore creates an overhead when running [Valgrind (`memcheck`)](http://valgrind.org/)/[DrMemory](http://www.drmemory.org/). So when invoking the program several times with different arguments, it takes up a considerable amount of time

My idea would be to use `fork()` right after the data loading phase and then hand the children off to Valgrind/DrMemory. Even if the loading phase runs under Valgrind/DrMemory, the overhead would only occur once and all `fork`ed child processes should be able to use the preloaded data from there.

Is it feasible to record a program state and declare it as untainted and then later restore that state in Valgrind (`memcheck`) or DrMemory?

**Note:** I'm only interested in unixoid platforms, limiting it to Linux alone would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My idea would be to use fork() right after the data loading phase and then hand the children off to Valgring/DrMemory.

That's not feasible for many reasons. For example, `glibc` will cache results of `syscall(SYS_getpid)` in an internal variable, and having multiple processes that believe they have the same pid (which `!=` their real pid) is an obvious recipe for disaster.

That said, what stops you from running `valgrind --trace-children=yes` and then `fork`ing child processes after initialization? Each of the child processes can do something like this:

```
char buf[PATH_MAX];
sprintf(buf, "/tmp/parameters-for-%d", getpid());
while (true) {
  if (FILE *fp = fopen(buf, "r")) {
    // read parameters for this child, and exercise appropriate code paths
    return run_with_parameters(fp);
  }
  sleep(1);
}
```

When you want child `N` to run, simply `echo "foo bar baz" > /tmp/parameters-for-N` and wait for it to complete. All other children will be nicely busy-waiting until you are ready to use them.

Comment: so what you say is to run it under Valgrind from the start and simply `fork()`?

Comment: @0xC0000022L Yes, exactly. No special support (beyond ability to trace children) necessary.

Comment: great, that actually answers my question to the point then. Спасибо большое!